# Google Analytics GetRequest Error: System.Net version 2.0.5.0 Needed to see HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using Google Analytics Core Reporting API. I can successfully run my request with a code like this.

```
DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest requestData = googleAnalyticsService.Data.Ga.Get(profiles, startDateStr, endDateStr, metrics);
requestData.Dimensions = dimensions;
requestData.MaxResults = Globals.MAX_RESULTS;

responseData = requestData.Execute();
```

So in my `responseData` object I have all the data that I need. But I also need to know when I have an error in my request. So I need to catch a `GoogleApiException` that has an `HttpStatusCode` property. This Http status code will let me know if I have reached my quota of requests per day so I can continue receiving information 24 hours after that. But when I catch an exception like this:

```
catch (GoogleApiException gapiex)
{
   logger.WriteToLog("GETPROFILEDATA", "Google API exception: " + gapiex.HttpStatusCode);
   break;
}
```

I get an error that says:

> The type 'System.Net.HttpStatusCode' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
>   Retargetable=Yes'.

And I cannot seem to find the library neither via NuGet nor elsewhere. 
Is there another way of getting the status code or does anyone have the library somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your .NET framework is patched. 
Microsoft released patches to .NET to allow Portable Class Libraries to properly find the appropriate runtime. KB2468871 patch is available at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556.

If you are seeing the above exception (or something like it), it means you're missing the latest .NET framework patches.

Comment: Hi, for info: My project runs in ISS 6.0 on windows server 2003 SP2. My project use Google.Apis and on server I take an error like this. I tried to patch the framework with this link.But it has some prerequisite updates. Please dont forget to install them beforehand.
They are KB2600217and KB2533523. I could patch framework with windows update.